# how can i use "ios bluetooth classic with swift"

Tags: ios-bluetooth

i have been searching and studying for long time
to find out "ios bluetooth classic" sample code.

but i can't find it.
just i found bluetooth low energy sample code.

but i need bluetooth classic swift at ios sample code

i think apple doesn't want us to use bluetooth  classic

i found sample code.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/using_core_bluetooth_classic

but i can't use this sample code .....

my plan is esp32 and iphone comunicate with each other by bluetooth classic, not by Bluetooth Low energy.

so , it is very difficult problem.

please help me

search and search...

Answer (score 0):

If you are a company or organisation looking to develop a classic Bluetooth accessory for iOS, then you need to apply for the [Apple MFi Programme](https://mfi.apple.com/). This will give you access to the necessary technical specifications, hardware components and certification tools.

If you're an individual, Apple recommends that you use a [third-party hobbyist](https://mfi.apple.com/en/who-should-join) solution to connect iOS devices to serial devices, but I haven't personally seen any.